# Failed prop type: Invalid prop `htmlAttributes` of type `boolean` supplied to `HelmetWrapper`, expected `object`

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

I have simply wrapped up description of my page in Helmet but then got the above mentioned error.

```
<Helmet htmlAttributes>
                <html lang="en" />
                <title>About Us - Portfolio Shop: We build for you</title>
                <meta name="description" content="We at Portfolio Shop are all about making an easy platform for students, job seekers and many others to create profile matching portfolios" />
</Helmet>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is clearly mentioned that you are passing ***htmlAttributes*** as a boolean value which is true by default and the type is valid. Either you can remove the prop or can update the prop value as mentioned in the [doc](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#readme)